# Is Cloudfront inherently faster than S3 (without considering distance)?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Just a simple question but I can't find a definitive answer online. Of course cloudfront is good for serving content globally, but is the infrastructure there inherently different from s3, so tha even if the distance to transfer is the same, cloudfront would genrrally be faster?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. CloudFront has lower latencies than S3 even when the request originates from a non-edge location. Generally, CloudFront responds *tens of milliseconds* faster. Whether you care about such small differences is a separate question.

References:

- http://www.quora.com/What-are-typical-latencies-for-static-content-in-S3-vs-Cloudfront
- http://readystate4.com/2012/07/09/amazon-s3-vs-amazon-cloudfront/